# How to Make Clickable <td>

Tags: html, html-table

I know there are many posts about this already, but I just can't get this to work.  All I want to do is have a full `<td>` be clickable.  I have a PHP loop that is generating this table and a simple piece of it is below.

```
<table id="reservation_table" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">      
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;"></th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">Dec. 18</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">Dec. 20</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">Dec. 21</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;" class="clickable">1:00-1:15</td>
    <td id="1" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;" class="clickable"><a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a></td>
    <td id="2" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;" class="clickable"><a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a></td>
    <td id="3" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;" class="clickable"><a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">4:00-4:15</td>
    <td id="28" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;" class="clickable"><a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a></td>
    <td id="29" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;" class="clickable"><a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a></td>
    <td id="30" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;"><a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

All I really need is the CSS to make the class "clickable" actually be clickable.  Right now it's....

```
.clickable{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Changing display to block not only messes up the formatting, but it also doesn't actually make the cell clickable.  It changes the cursor to the pointer hand on hover, but the actual clicking to go to a website doesn't work.

Comment: btw u r using the `.clickable` on the `td` so `display: table-cell` doesnt make any difference.

Comment: do you want all the td elements to be clickable?you can have simple javascript code to do that

Comment: you mean : when you click on a td so it navigate you to the link that is inside it  O.o ?  in other words you want that that td should be behave like a ?

Comment: @Tiger: Yes.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: by filling a in td , answer is already given, to see the effect first remove that 5px padding in td :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u should never use the table tags instead use the css ,here is the answer to ur question

**HTML**

```
<div class="table" id="reservation_table">      
  <div class="row">
    <p></p>
    <p>Dec. 18</p>
    <p>Dec. 20</p>
    <p>Dec. 21</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>1:00-1:15</p>
    <a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a>
    <a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a>
    <a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>4:00-4:15</p>
    <a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a>
    <a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a>
    <a href="http://somewhere.com">Reserve slot</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid; 
    padding: 5px;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

a,p {
    background: yellow; // for demonstration
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid; 
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I took some of what you posted and made my own solution. Therefore, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Flimm i updated the answer to reflect correct html

Answer (score 1):

My answer users JQuery for the solution.

To setup the html I use the class attribute and data-href.

`<td class='clickable' data-href='www.knowhere.com'>Put anything you want here</td>`

Then at the bottom of the page I insert the JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(".clickable").click(function(){
           window.location = $(this).data("href");
     });
</script>
```

So how this works is that the JQuery targets the class attribute looking for the clickable tag we used and once that region is clicked it causes the data-href to be used and changes the page location.

By doing it this way all the elements that have the clickable tag and href-data provided now become hyperlinks.

There are a few things that you miss out on doing it this way instead of just embedding a hyperlink into the cell.

- No blue underline
- No URL path at bottom of browser
- Its not clearly a link

But some of these can easily be added.

The upside is that the entire cell becomes clickable, not just the text.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the `<a>` inside of `clickable` fills out the whole `td`

```
.clickable a {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't make the cell able to be clicked though, although I do now get the background color change I was also hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  the full td elements act like a link, you should probably do this.It will make your whole td clickable with the use of some simple javascript.Here as an example it will change the td background color red when clicked

```js
   var input=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
       (function (i){
         input[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
      e.target.style.background='red';
   });
    })(i)
   }
```

```html
<table id="reservation_table" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">      

  <tr>
     <td style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;" ><a href='http://somewhere.com'>1:00-1:15</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```